# Relacionamento Django Models

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django

Eu tenho um *model* chamado `Item` e fiz um chamado `Compra`. Eu consegui relacionar vários itens com cada compra, porém não sei como relacionar a quantidade de cada item em cada compra.

```
class Item(models.Model):
nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
estoque = models.PositiveIntegerField('Estoque', blank=False, default=0)
estoque_min = models.PositiveIntegerField('Estoque Min', blank=False, default=0)
slug = models.SlugField('Atalho')

def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
```

Model Compra:

```
class Compra(models.Model):
fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(Fornecedor, verbose_name='Fornecedor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
item = models.ManyToManyField(Item, verbose_name='Item', related_name='Itens')
data_compra = models.DateTimeField('Data de Compra', auto_now=True)
data_entrega = models.DateTimeField('Data de Entrega')
entregue = models.BooleanField('Entregue', default=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('compras/' + str(self.pk))
```

Fiz um relacionamento *many-to-many* com os itens, no Django Admin ficou assim:

[image: Django Admin]

Queria uma sugestão de qual lógica utilizar para colocar quantidade em cada item selecionado, sendo esta quantidade relacionado a cada compra, e não com o estoque do item.

**EDIT:** Utilizei o through e deu certo, porém o problema é outro.

```
def compras_detalhe(request, pk):
compras = Compra.objects.all().filter(id=pk)

itens = []
for compra in compras:
    for item in compra.itens.all():
        print(item)
        itens.append(item)
```

Com este código eu consigo exibir os itens que foram comprado, porém não consigo acessar o campo quantidade, que está no model ItemCompra (intermediário no through).

```
class Compra(models.Model):
fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(Fornecedor, verbose_name='Fornecedor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
itens = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='ItemCompra')
cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name='Cliente', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
data_compra = models.DateTimeField('Data de Compra', auto_now=True)
data_entrega = models.DateTimeField('Data de Entrega')
nota_fiscal = models.CharField('Nota Fiscal', max_length=100, default='-')
entregue = models.BooleanField('Entregue', default=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('compras/' + str(self.pk))

class ItemCompra(models.Model):
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name='Item', related_name='Itens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantidade = models.IntegerField('Quantidade', default=0)
compra_id = models.ForeignKey(Compra, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Compra', null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return (self.item.nome + str(self.quantidade))

class Item(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
    unidade = models.ForeignKey(Unidade, verbose_name='Unidade', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    estoque = models.PositiveIntegerField('Estoque', blank=False, default=0)
    estoque_min = models.PositiveIntegerField('Estoque Min', blank=False, default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField('Atalho')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Comment: Você precisa de outra relação: `CompraItem`, que relaciona o item com a compra possuindo a quantidade. Uma `Compra` possui um ou mais `CompraItem`, que está associado a um `Item`.

Comment: Ah, entendi, faz sentido muito obrigado.

Comment: Lembre-se que você vai ter que salvar a maioria dos dados dos itens na tabela `CompraItem`. Pois quando a compra for realizada, dados como preço devem ser salvo separado, senão todas as comprar se tornarão inválidas quando alguém precisar atualizar os preços dos items. Ex: Compro um item por 2 dinheiros e ano que vem o preço é reajustado para 3 dinheiros. A conta que já foi paga não pode ter esta alteração, apenas para as novas compras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o parâmetro `through` do `ManyToManyField` para definir um *model* que servirá de conexão entre os outros dois. Nesse *model* você pode colocar dados adicionais:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)

class Compra(models.Model):
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item, verbose_name='Item', 
        related_name='Itens', through='ItemCompra')
    data_compra = models.DateTimeField('Data de Compra', auto_now=True)

class ItemCompra(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    compra = models.ForeignKey(Compra)
    qtd = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Comment: Dúvida rápida: quando seleciono os items da compra eu obtenho um objeto `Item` ou um objeto `ItemCompra` (ou algum personalizado pelo Django)?